# WTelegramClient on Azure Function session file is being used by another process

Tags: c#, telegram-api, wtelegramclient

I made a simple Azure Function using `WTelegramClient`.
It is configured to run every 10 minutes and session file is created without any problems.

In logs, however, I see that it runs successfully only around once an hour, another 5 times it throws following error:

```
The process cannot access the file 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\WTelegram.session' because it is being used by another process.
```

This is a session file path configured in App:

```
case "session_pathname": return Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "WTelegram.session");
```

Deployment is done through VS 2022 as a Zip Package.

Please help.

Comment: UPDATE: I was missing using statement when initialized client. Now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dispose` the client when you're done using it

Comment: Please add more details and code.